# Cannot delete O365 Bot

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

We have created a Microsoft Azure Bot that we now need to delete and reinstate. However, we are unable to find any means to delete / overlay the bot and have instead been forced to create a new bot with a slight variation on the name.

Is there anyway to delete all reference to a given bot such that the name may be re-used for a new bot creation?

Comment: Hi Bruce. I'm not sure what you mean by O365 bot. Is it just a bot that is connected to the Skype channel?

Comment: For removal of a bot in Azure, you can go to the all resources tab (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseAll) and filter on the following under type: App Service, Bot Service, App Service Plan. You might also have some storage account tied to this (or more) services. Please be sure that you are removing what is needed. Additionally, you can make sure there is no APP associated with the bot by going to The Azure AD App Registrations (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredAppsPreview)

Comment: Thank you for your help Dana - you are correct that this is an Azure bot connected to Skype. I will check with the team and see if your proposal works (assuming this has not already been tried).